# Tuning Geoserver datastore with gsconfig

Tags: python, geoserver, gsconfig

I'm trying to create a datastore in Geoserver with gsconfig and it works, up to a point where i want to enable for instance "Expose primary keys" or "Support on the fly geometry simplification" tags on the datastore.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
     ds = catalog.create_datastore(store_name, workspace_name)

     ds.connection_parameters.update({'host': host, 
                                      'port':port,
                                       'database': database,
                                       'user': user_name,
                                       'passwd': pw, 'dbtype':db_type,
                                       'schema': schema, 
                                       'Expose primary keys': 'true'})
```

The update method on connection_parameters accepts a dictionary as input where the keys can be set.